# Python - Unable to use python-firebase on Windows

Tags: python, firebase

I'm a python beginner and I've been struggling with [ozgur/python-firebase](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase) git repository, I followed the 'Getting Started' section in the docs and got this error:

[image]

I am using Windows 7, I installed Python 3 and pip and all the other dependencies mentioned in the repository such as:

> $ sudo pip install requests
>
> $ sudo pip install python-firebase

And yet it does not work. However, when I follow the same steps on my Linux server, it works as expected, I get a list of all my firebase records. What am I missing (In Windows)?

Code:

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://blsblabla.firebaseio.com', None)
result = firebase.get('/place', None)
print (result)
input()
```

Comment: Can you please tell us your Python version on Linux and Windows?

Comment: Windows - 3.7.0
Linux - 2.7.9

Comment: Seems to be a python version related issue, can you try to replicate the exact working environment in windows?